# semget: how to avoid concurrent access to semaphore group on its creating/initialization?

Tags: c, perl, unix, ipc, semaphore

When i've create semaphore group id with semget (passing IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL flags) - in general case my semaphores inside the group is not initialized and may contain "random values".

So i need to initialize all semaphores right after getting id of the newly-created semaphore group.

My question is:

How to avoid potential race conditions between       `semgrpID=semget(semgrpKey,nSemaphores,IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL);`
and
`semctl(semgrpID,0,SETALL,...);` 
?

Comment: The process that creates the semaphore needs to complete initialization before any processes that use the semaphore are created. The typical way to handle this is to create/init the semaphore and then fork/exec the other processes.

Comment: Processes accessing this semaphore group may start from crond, from CLI and can be initialized from webserver.
It is not forked from one single process. So i need to protect semaphore  group itself, but for this i need... semaphore somewhere?

Comment: Then as part of the startup sequence, you need to run a program that creates and initializes the semaphore group. It has to finish before any programs that use the semaphores are allowed to start.

Comment: Or i can use flock when adding semaphore group, but i use semaphore group exactly to avoid using any flocks. Hmm... I hope, that using one flock instead of 10 (which was replaced by semaphores) - is a good compromise.

Comment: I think, i know answer for my question. It is: "DONT use legacy semget/semop/semctl", use POSIX semaphores instead. POSIX's function sem_open support creation+initialization in one atomic action.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using POSIX semaphores instead of SYSV semaphores.  The POSIX design is simpler and cleaner; for example, POSIX semaphores are created with specified initial values.

SYSV semaphores do, however, have some capabilities that POSIX semaphores do not, such as undoable operations and working with multi-element semaphore *sets*.  If you must use the SYSV flavor, then ...

I suppose you imagine using a well-known key for the semaphore set, so that you have no control over the timing with which processes other than the one designated to create the semaphore set access the set.  In the worst case, you might have multiple processes all attempting to get a semaphore set via the same key and with `IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL`, with the one that succeeds being responsible for the initialization, and those that get `EEXIST` trying again without those flags.  Indeed, that does produce a mess.

If you have a situation in which a well-known semaphore set key is used by unrelated processes, then the associated semaphore set is a system resource, not belonging to any of the processes individually.  In that case, you should have programs dedicated to initializing and managing it.  These should be connected to your system initialization framework.

It would also be possible to use some other form of mutual exclusion to protect initialization of the semaphore set.  For example, you might use a lock file.  You might even use a POSIX semaphore for this limited purpose.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what i want to know!